# PagerSlidingTabStrip Library - Changing the tab to holo dark

Tags: android

I've made an app using the PagerSliderTabStrip library (https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip)

It is a library that emulates the Play Store's colorful tabs. I was looking through the code but I cannot find where the background for the tabs are defined - I would like to know how would I be able to change the colors of the tab to a Holo Dark themed tab. I've already tried messing with all of the attributes (located [here](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip/blob/master/library/res/values/attrs.xml)) but couldn't get anything working.

Comment: Link is not working : 
https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip/blob/master/library/res/values/attrs.xml%29

Comment: Thanks for sharing this link. I just loved the library.
https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip

To me this is not clear : 
"the background for the tabs are defined". 
If you are talking about tab's below color then that is getting from :

activity_main.xml --> ImageView --> android:background="#FF666666" and if you are talking about whole background of tab then :

<com.astuetz.viewpager.extensions.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:background="@drawable/background_tabs" />

Thank you. Hope this will help you. Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks for the help! I see that I need to modify the background_tabs drawable and the text color of the tabs, but I don't know what color the default Action Bar tabs are. I've looked it up but I can't find them.